# displaying wordpress recent posts on a template page with previous and next controls

Tags: php, wordpress, posts

I'm using a wp-query to display on a template page the 5 most recent posts.
it works fine, I want also to add previous and next button to navigate to the previous 5 posts, and so on.

I set 'showposts=5', it displays the 5 most recents post, that's perfect, but when clicking on "previous", it redirect me to /page/2/, but the 5 same posts are displayed...

here is my code :

```
<?php
    $temp = $wp_query; $wp_query= null;
    $wp_query = new WP_Query(); $wp_query->query('showposts=5' . '&paged='.$paged);
    while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>

      <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_time('y-m-d'); ?> | <?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
<?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php if ($paged > 1) { ?>

    <nav id="nav-posts">
      <div class="prev"><?php next_posts_link('PREVIOUS POSTS'); ?></div>
      <div class="next"><?php previous_posts_link('NEXT POSTS'); ?></div>
    </nav>

    <?php } else { ?>

    <nav id="nav-posts">
      <div class="prev"><?php next_posts_link('PREVIOUS POSTS'); ?></div>
    </nav>

    <?php } ?>

    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

anyone can help me with this ?
I don't know where's the problem...

thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you are not using the $paged variable;

use `$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;`

before the WP_Query() function

Comment: thanks for your reply @anstrangel0ver but I don't understand the purpose.. can you please explain ?

Comment: actually the above code is get_query_var('paged') get the value 2 from the url http://url/page/2. if page is not set it will give value 1. paged parameter is used to define that its on which page. so if $paged is 1 it will show the first 5 post if $page is 2 it will show the post from 6 to 10.. so goes on

Comment: thanks @anstrangel0ver, I'm using this now, but it still doesn't work...
<?php
   $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $temp = $wp_query; $wp_query= null;
    $wp_query = new WP_Query(); $wp_query->query('showposts=5' . '&paged='.$paged);
    while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>

Comment: do you know why ? Is it possible that I have a problem in my wp-includes codes ? I didn't change anything inside

Comment: check :- is it still showing the same 5 posts? and do you have more than 5 posts? if yes then try to put $paged=2 and cheeck

Comment: thanks for your help @anstrangel0ver, everything works fine !

Answer (score 0):

Hello Display Recent Post with  Pagination

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

<!-- Add the pagination functions here. -->

<!-- Start of the main loop. -->
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();  ?>

<!-- the rest of your theme's main loop -->

<?php endwhile; ?>
<!-- End of the main loop -->

<!-- Add the pagination functions here. -->

<div class="nav-previous alignleft"><?php next_posts_link( 'Older posts' ); ?></div>
<div class="nav-next alignright"><?php previous_posts_link( 'Newer posts' ); ?></div>

<?php else : ?>
<p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```